# Can I run away from dragons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any point to fighting dragons? No one is really helping me, I almost killed the dragon by myself and I think one of my spells touched someone and the whole town went after me. They saved the dragon, since I had to run.

Is there any point in fighting those random dragon attacks? Can I just runaway?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dragon fights give you a dragon soul, and a bunch of dragon scales and bones. Dragon souls are used to unlock new shout after you've learned a word, whereas scales and bones are used to forge one of the best armor in the game, both light and heavy.

If you need none of these, you can try to run away from random dragon fight. But keep in mind that dragons are fast and will follow you for quite a while, so you should be prepared to take quite a bit of damages while running away. (Assuming they're breathing at you)

Comment: Honestly, I find the biggest problem I have running away from random dragons is that they have an annoying tendency to kill NPC's that I would prefer they didn't.

Comment: You have to start running and get far enough away to fast travel before the NPC gets devoured. But they are pretty squishy.

Comment: One thing, though, is that the dragon bones and scales used for armor a) require a Smithing skill of 100, b) can be found as random loot, and c) only require 14 scales for a fully upgraded set (for Dragonscale, but Dragonbone is similar), which can require killing as few as 5 dragons. Oh, and they're _heavy_. ;) I find myself just taking the gold from a dragon and leaving the rest at this point.

Comment: Fizzy's right nothing worse than your running away turning almost an entire town of nonessential npc's in useless worm food. ie shop owners and such,don't run,lol

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run away from random Dragon fights but it's likely they will follow you and cause some damage before you finally lose them. There are dragons that you will have to face on the main quest line though.

My advice would be to fight them, once killed they provide you with dragon bone and scales which are quite valuable and can be used to forge some of the strongest armour (it's also a lot of fun!). If you're not interested in the armour or the money you can generate from selling their bones and scale's then no, there is no point in killing the random dragons.

If you're still having trouble killing dragons have a look [**here**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon) at each of their weaknesses.

Hope thats helpful :)

Comment: Umm... You can absolutely unlock shouts using random dragon souls. It's how I've unlocked nearly every shout I know.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Oops your right, I forgot you have to use the soul to unlock it, my bad :)